# with MVC 4.0, RedirectToAction does not render PartialView as Partial, it send a whole page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-5.0, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I got something a little complicated, but I don't see why it would not work:
I have a JSTree in my Index.cshtml. When a node is selected, I make an Ajax call to

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEBooksItems(string id)
```

which return a partial view. This works PERFECTLY WELL.

Now, in addition to the tree search, I have a form to add some criterias to narrow down the search. I use Ajax.BeginForm to Post data back to the controller.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetEBooksCustom(GenericSearchViewModel filter)
    {            
        vm = filter;
        //Session["GenreNodeId"] = id;
        Session["SearchCondition"] = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.Condition) != true) ? vm.Condition : "All";
        Session["MaximumPrice"] = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.MaxPrice) != true) ? vm.MaxPrice : "999999";
        Session["MinimumPrice"] = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.MinPrice) != true) ? vm.MinPrice : "0";
        Session["SearchIndex"] = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SearchIndex) != true) ? vm.SearchIndex : "KindleStore";
        Session["SortOrder"] = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SortOrder) != true) ? vm.SortOrder : "price";
        Session["KeyWords"] = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.Keywords) != true) ? vm.Keywords : "";
        Session["Title"] = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.Title) != true) ? vm.Title : "";
        Session["Author"] = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.Author) != true) ? vm.Author : "";
        return RedirectToAction("GetEBooksItems", new { id = vm.CategoryNodeId });                                    
    }
```

to this method, wich in turn call the first one with a RedirectToAction.

I have been trying everything I could think of, I always get the results as a whole page, instead of a Partial view, like in the first method.

It looks like the call to GetEBooksCustom is not "seen" as an Ajax call. 
What do I miss? 
Thanks for your help,
Bernard.

*******Edit 6 hours later***********************

In between i did what was suggested, that is to extract the functionalities from "GetEBooksItems", to be able to directly return a PartialView instead of using RedirectToAction. In the debugger, it looks like everything is perfect, I see a 200 answer from the server, BUT I still get a full page display, and the url display the controller method, while this should not be the case for an ajax call.

The thing is, I have basically the same form somewhere else, where it works as expected. Can't see what could be different???

As always, thanks for your help and suggestions.
Bernard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) instead of Ajax.BeginForm. After loosing hours on this, it took me about 10 minutes to get it working exactly as expected!

For those who might be interested, here are the 2 type of coding one above the other:

```
    //using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetEBooksCustom", "Home", new AjaxOptions {
    //                            UpdateTargetId = "ListOfBooksHere", 
    //                          HttpMethod = "POST",                                    
    //                          OnBegin="ShowProcessingMsg",
    //                          OnComplete="HideProcessingMsg"


    $("#eBooksForm").ajaxForm({
        url: "/home/GetEBooksCustom",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#ListOfBooksHere").html(data);
        }
    });
```

I did not bother with OnBegin and OnComplete, as I am using this:

```
    $(document).ajaxSend(function() {
        $('.loadingIndicator').show();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $('.loadingIndicator').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that this is happening because `RedirectToAction` returns a 302 to your browser instructing it to, quite literally, redirect to the other action. Your browser's handling this by redirecting the whole page. You should (depending somewhat on the content of the `GetEBooksItems` method, be able to get around this simply by calling the other method directly instead of using the redirect:

```
return GetEBooksItems(vm.CategoryNodeId);
```

Or, better still, abstract the logic from `GetEBooksItems` into a separate method, reuse it in `GetEBooksCustom` and return the `PartialView` directly. That way you don't have to work around the redirect at all.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I thought after thinking a bit more about this. I need a method returning the main part of "vm", so that I could return it along with the partialView instead of using a RedirectTo Action. Thank you! Sometimes, just asking, and having a second pair of eyes lookng, is enough to get the answer.... :-)